# Working with Mainframe application in Blue Prism.

Tags: mainframe, blueprism

I've been working whit Blue Prism on a project that was using at one point IBM mainframe application(ICBS). I've mange to get it working, but only problem that I had was Login in to therminal.

My robot lunched application as mainframe app, but after that therminal is asking me to login in, but its doing that in standard Win window - whit option to enter login and password.
Problem is that Blue Prism is not able to spy on thoes elements because it's launched as mainframe.

If I launch this app as standard win application, then there is no problem in login in, but after that working whit mainframe screen is imposible because I can't spy on specyfic elements of the green screens.

I was trying to launched as mainframe, then using another object(Win app) to logon and then go back to mainframe but I cant to Attach Win app Object to allready launched mainframe object. I get "could not be found" error when I'm tring to Attach.

Any idea how to get it working?

Cheers,
RAFEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's no other way than having two different objects.

- The first one should be the "Mainframe Application" object that is launching from executable file.
- The second one should be the "Windows Applications" object that is attaching to appearing window.

I am guessing that you're having a problem with attaching the second object to the window.

The Blue Prism when trying to attach to the object is checking two things:

- The name of the process - you can find that information using task manager.
- The window title of the target Application - that's the title that is visible at the top of the window.

There is possibility to use *,# and others as wildcard characters.

You'll have to try there around there to get that working.

Below you can find a print screen of one of mine objects that attaches to windows photo viewer.

[image: Here you can find a print screen of one of mine objects that attaches to windows photo viewer.]

Comment: That was my idea aswell, so thx for conformation that Im on the right tracks. I'm try to use wildcards in window title but still I have problems whit it.

Andrzej, jest jakiś sposób aby nawiązać kontatkt poza SO??